# asp.net get specific Values in sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

in my Sql Database i have

```
 ID Name Cost Weight
 1 John  15   36
 2 Mike  8    45
 3 Smith 10   12
```

i have a dropdownlist

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MainCost" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM [Human]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

containg the value of the names and a button that when clicked it should multiply the Cost*Weight, how would i get the specific values to multiply? i also have a Class for DbConnctivity
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a `function` for getting the `Cost*Weight` value of `selected user` from `DropdownList`. you can call that function whenever user is selected from `DropDownList` and `Button` is `Clicked`

Note: Please change `ConnectionString` and `UIControl` Names asper your requirement

**Complete Code:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
       int TotalCostWeight=getTotalWeightandCost();    
        }

     private   int getTotalWeightandCost()
        {
            int total = 0;
            String strCon = "Data Source=systemname;Initial Catalog=databasename;uid=uid;pwd=pwd;Integrated Security=True;";
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCon))
            {
                String strCmd = "SELECT Cost*Weight as total FROM [Human] WHERE [Name] = @Name";
                using(SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(strCmd, sqlCon))
                sqlCon.Open();
                command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
                SqlDataReader sReader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (sReader.Read())
                    total = Convert.ToInt32(sReader[0].ToString());
            }
        }
            return total;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT Cost* Weight FROM [Human] WHERE [Name] = @Name`

(place the string instead of the @Name or use SQL Parameters)

Example for SQL Parameter:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Jhon";
```